# Add a web page to a site built in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am a sort-of newbie with MVC and Zend in particular.  I have taken over a project from another team, site is built in Zend framework.  There is an admin dashboard to add content, assets like images and media, a blog and a portal into Zen Cart for the store.

What is the easiest method of adding a new web page that has as its contents several things that are dynamic - items for sale, music to listen to, blog entries, news items from the database and a featured artist.  All of this is stored in the MySQL db.  I just do not know enough about MVC to make it work correctly.

I can create a page in the admin dashboard and use as the URL another "module" that already exists, but if I attempt to copy a module folder (for instance the folder called musiclive is almost exactly what I need except I need to add another column of elements...) the admin dashboard does not render.  I know that I need to create some sort of "view" and fiddle with or create a controller, but not sure of the easiest method of doing this.  I probably have to tell the admin dashboard I have added another "module" but it really is just the main or home page of the site - the other guys never built it because it was rich with details and I guess they put it off.  I also probably have to change the files inside the module folder to reflect a different page.

Would love some help or pointers.  Ask if you need more details on what the heck I am describing here...

Answer (score 2):

Create a new controller in that same module instead of copying the whole module if the module is so similar to your requirements. And then extend already built resources like forms, models. I strongly recommend you to read about zend framework documentation, especially skeleton application tutorial. That will increase your knowledge as well as make you understand MVC and your current project.

http://framework.zend.com/learn/

One more thing there are 2 versions of zend framework and both are entirely different. You need to know the version in which the project is built. Zend framework 2 has following **generic** directory structure:

```
config/
   autoload/
   application.config.php
module
   Application/
      config/
      src/
      view
      Module.php
   SomeOtherModule/
   ...
public/
vendor/
```

Comment: The new controller in the same module sounds like the answer.  Thank you for the suggestion to read the docs on skeleton application.  I believe that the framework is version 1 not 2, as the directory structure is not like what you describe above.  Will reply back with what I come up with.